# How to load local JSON to create a d3 chart without a local server?

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

I'm trying to replicate the following d3 chart locally: 
http://bl.ocks.org/eesur/be2abfb3155a38be4de4

How can I load the JSON file?

Comment: Did my answer and the fiddle solve the problem? If yes, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do ajax to the filesystem. Either you set up a local webserver or you copy the content of the `marvel.json` file into the script:

```
 var json = {
  "name": "marvel",
  "img": "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/marvel.png",
  "children": [
   {
    "name": "Heroes",
    "children": [
     {
       "hero": "Spider-Man",

 ....


vis = d3.select("#vis").append("svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

root = json;
root.fixed = true;
root.x = w / 2;
root.y = h / 4;

    // Build the path
var defs = vis.insert("svg:defs")
  .data(["end"]);
```

You need to replace the function `d3.json("marvel.json", function(json) {` with the assignment to the `json` variable.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on the second part with the full code?

Comment: Updated answer to show the block where I removed the ajax call. The complete working example is here: https://jsbin.com/yibuwucafi/edit?html,js,output